# Python Function Won't Run At ALL?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to the programming world and am wondering why the following code will not only refuse to run, but my python software won't even give me any error messages whatsoever.I'm using Pythonista, an IOS app for python. I can't get the app to run this code (and it won't give me any error messages) and was wondering if it's my code itself, or is it just the application. Any knowledge on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
def starBits():
    badMatchups = [Zelda, Cloud, Ryu]
    worstMatchups = [Jigglypuff, Villager, Bayonetta]
    print(badMatchups)[1:2]
    print(worstMatchups)[1:1]

def main():
    starBits()

main()
```

Comment: This raises an exception, namely `NameError` since `Zelda`, `Cloud` and the others are not defined. Were the elements of the list initially quotes or is this the way you have typed them?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: How are you attempting to run this? I would expect a NameError, but you say you're not getting any error messages.

Comment: You mention "the tester". What is this tester? How do you interact with it, and exactly what feedback does it provide?

Comment: I'm using Pythonista, an IOS app for python. I can't get the app to run this code (and it won't give me any error messages)  and was wondering if it's my code itself, or is it just the application.

Comment: See if you can run any code at all, including code that would be expected to raise an exception (`1/0`) and code that would be expected to run fine (`print("Hello world.")`).

Comment: It has run other programs I've made just fine, and I've changed the values in the lists to strings but still no luck, this how my current code looks:def starBits():     badMatchups = ["Zelda", "Cloud", "Ryu"]     worstMatchups = ["Jigglypuff", "Villager", "Bayonetta"]     print(badMatchups[1:3])     print(worstMatchups[1:2])          def main():      starBits()           main()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect from this, but it's *really* funky syntax.

```
print(badMatchups)[1:2]
print(worstMatchups)[1:1]
```

If those slices are subscripts for the lists, you need them inside the call to **print**:

```
print(badMatchups[1:2])
print(worstMatchups[1:1])
```

By the way, do you realize that [1:1] is an empty slice?  The second number is the first position *not* included.  You may need

```
print(badMatchups[1:3])     # two elements
print(worstMatchups[1:2])   # one element
```

---

Also, are those elements external variables, or are they supposed to be literal names?  If the latter, then you have to put them in quotation marks.

```
badMatchups = ["Zelda", "Cloud", "Ryu"]
worstMatchups = ["Jigglypuff", "Villager", "Bayonetta"]
```

With this change, the code runs; I hope it's what you want.

---

Can't get it to run?  Reality check time ...

**Full code, changes made**:

```
def starBits():
    badMatchups = ["Zelda", "Cloud", "Ryu"]
    worstMatchups = ["Jigglypuff", "Villager", "Bayonetta"]
    print(badMatchups[1:3])
    print(worstMatchups[1:2])

def main():
    starBits()

main()
```

Output:

```
['Cloud', 'Ryu']
['Villager']
```

Comment: I thought they might be external symbols (or an obvious syntax message), and a comment already covered those.

Comment: Amendment accepted.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I did make the values strings and fix my syntax but it still won't run... Thank you for your help though.

Comment: My example above works in both Python2.7 and Python3 (that's 3.5.2).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how my code is line for line, I guess this is an issue I need to report to the app developer.

Comment: Wait! I ran your code and it ran.... Just found out the issue was because I had the main indented in line with the function itself...... And the software wouldn't tell me this.... Thank you for all you help.

Comment: Ha!  Yes, you rarely want to recur on the main program.  Anyway, that's why I posted the code; I knew we were close, and it helps check for an exact match.